# Join_room in flask-socketio, TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to create a room and get the output on the client side through the `emit`, but it doesn't seem to work.
can you please tell me what's wrong with it.

I think this is the error but I can't figure out what it means:-

> participants = ns[room[0]]._fwdm.copy() if room[0] in ns else {}
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

> File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\app.py", line 36, in join_roomm
> emit('room joined', "Heyy I've joined the room", to = room)

here are my server side codes:-

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit, join_room

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

client = 0

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/home')
def home():
   return render_template('home.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect_handerler(data):
    global client
    client = client +1
    print(f"\n\n {client}\n\n")
   

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect_handeler():
    global client
    client = client -1
    print(f"\n\n {client}\n\n")
    

@socketio.on('join')
def join_roomm(data):
    room = data['room']
    join_room(room)
    emit('room joined', "Heyy I've joined the room", to = room)   //Line 36


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug = True)
```

Here are my client side codes:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
Index
<button onclick="room(1)">
Room1
</button>
    <button onclick="room(2)">
Room2
    </button>
        
 <button id="message" onclick="message()">Send a message to server</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script >
    var socket = io();
     socket.on('clients count', function(client){
      // console.log(client);

     });
     socket.on('message', function(data){
        console.log(data);
     });

    function room(id){
        // console.log(id);
        socket.emit('join',{"room": id});
    };

    socket.on('room joined', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the error that I am getting:-

```
 self.run()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 690, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 714, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 284, in _handler
    return self._handle_event(handler, message, namespace, sid,
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 767, in _handle_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\app.py", line 36, in join_roomm
    emit('room joined', "Heyy I've joined the room", to = room)
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 839, in emit
    return socketio.emit(event, *args, namespace=namespace, to=to,
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 462, in emit
    self.server.emit(event, *args, namespace=namespace, to=to,
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 294, in emit
    self.manager.emit(event, data, namespace, room=room,
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\socketio\base_manager.py", line 161, in emit
    for sid, eio_sid in self.get_participants(namespace, room):
  File "E:\KabirProject\WebsocketDocs\websocketsenv\lib\site-packages\socketio\base_manager.py", line 45, in get_participants
    participants = ns[room[0]]._fwdm.copy() if room[0] in ns else {}
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because I was trying to pass an integer in the `to` parameter and I think it only accepts string so when I started passing string It started working.